# Position of the button is off on IE and FF

Tags: html, css

How do I match the style (and also the position is off) of the button on

http://jsfiddle.net/nA4P9/21/

using the compatible codes in CSS?

See image attached from different browsers - [image: IE]Chrome/IE/FF. [image: FF] [image: Chrome]

CSS -

```
.FindHome {background-color:#09F; width:300px; border:1px solid #09F; padding:10px 40px 10px 15px; border-radius:5px; display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background: #09F url('http://www.magnixsolutions.com/clients/tas/img/arrow.png') no-repeat; background-position:320px center; margin-bottom:35px; overflow: hidden; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;}
.FindHome:hover {border:1px solid #4d4d4d; background: #4d4d4d url('http://www.magnixsolutions.com/clients/tas/img/arrow.png') no-repeat;  background-position:320px center;}
.FindHome-div{display:inline-block;}
```

HTML -

```
<div class="fluid FindHome-div">
    <h1><a href="http://www.ntreisinnovia.net/ntr/idx/index.php?key=b74b4ef49443e4ac6699324016bbaec5" class="FindHome" target="_blank">Find your home </a></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just add screenshots

Comment: I tested this in the latest versions of Chrome, FF, and IE. I don't see any issues.

Comment: I didn't see any difference either.

Comment: Did you see the button aligned perfectly next to "Start bidding on..." button and match the style on http://jsfiddle.net/nA4P9/21/ ?